# DNS anycast on Windows Domain Controller

Tags: dns-hosting, microsoft

Is Windows 2016/2019 DC DNS (AD integrated zones) capable of supporting anycast? Can workstations perform secure dynamic update on anycast DNS? Thanks!

Already read the below article but didn't mention whether it can support secure dynamic update.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/deploy/anycast